# How can I optimize this group wise max sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

This is what I want. It basically grabs all records from the `daily_statistics` table and groups by `user_id`. At the same time, it does the following:

1. The values of the user are grouped by most recent
2. `attachment_ids` are represented as an array, so I can determine how many attachments the user has

The result:

```
 user_id | country_id |       time_at       | assumed_gender |    attachment_ids
---------+------------+---------------------+----------------+----------------------
   21581 |        172 | 2015-04-18 17:55:00 |                | [5942]
   21610 |        140 | 2015-04-18 19:55:00 | male           | [5940]
   22044 |        174 | 2015-04-18 21:55:00 | female         | [12312313, 12312313]

   21353 |        174 | 2015-04-18 20:59:00 | male           | [5938]
   21573 |        246 | 2015-04-18 21:57:00 | male           | [5936]
(5 rows)
```

The follwoing query executes slow. Something like 17 seconds.

```
  SELECT
    ds.user_id,
    max(case when id=maxid then country_id end) AS country_id,
    max(case when id=maxid then time_at end) AS time_at,
    max(case when id=maxid then properties->'assumed_gender' end) AS assumed_gender,
    json_agg(to_json(attachment_id)) AS attachment_ids
  FROM daily_statistics ds JOIN (
      SELECT u.id as user_id, (
        SELECT ds2.id FROM daily_statistics ds2 WHERE ds2.user_id=u.id AND ds2.metric = 'participation' AND ds2.status = 'active' AND ds2.campaign_id = 39
        ORDER BY ds2.id DESC LIMIT 1
      ) AS maxid FROM users u
      WHERE u.properties -> 'provider' IN ('twitter')
  ) mu ON (ds.user_id=mu.user_id)
  WHERE ds.campaign_id = 39 AND ds.metric = 'participation' AND ds.status = 'active'
  GROUP BY ds.user_id;
```

The issue is with the group wise max statement. Is there a way to optimize this query and get the same output? I was thinking of using some kind of lateral join? But then I wouldn't be able to get the number of `attachment_id`'s per user.

Edit: On records that are 9k++, with a table size of 2m rows: It takes around 25 seconds to execute this query.

```
foobar_production=> EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
foobar_production->     ds.user_id,
foobar_production->     max(case when id=maxid then country_id end) AS country_id,
foobar_production->     max(case when id=maxid then time_at end) AS time_at,
foobar_production->     max(case when id=maxid then properties->'assumed_gender' end) AS assumed_gender,
foobar_production->     json_agg(to_json(attachment_id)) AS attachment_ids
foobar_production->   FROM daily_statistics ds JOIN (
foobar_production(>       SELECT u.id as user_id, (
foobar_production(>         SELECT ds2.id FROM daily_statistics ds2 WHERE ds2.user_id=u.id AND ds2.metric = 'participation' AND ds2.status = 'active' AND ds2.campaign_id = 4742
foobar_production(>         ORDER BY ds2.id DESC LIMIT 1
foobar_production(>       ) AS maxid FROM users u
foobar_production(>       WHERE u.properties -> 'provider' IN ('twitter')
foobar_production(>   ) mu ON (ds.user_id=mu.user_id)
foobar_production->   WHERE ds.campaign_id = 4742 AND ds.metric = 'participation' AND ds.status = 'active'
foobar_production->   GROUP BY ds.user_id;
                                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=2063.07..2063.08 rows=1 width=103) (actual time=25155.963..25156.859 rows=775 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..1883.99 rows=2 width=103) (actual time=0.744..382.699 rows=2787 loops=1)
         ->  Index Scan using index_daily_statistics_on_campaign_id_and_type on daily_statistics ds  (cost=0.56..1621.73 rows=31 width=99) (actual time=0.107..33.513 rows=9751 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (campaign_id = 4742)
               Filter: (((metric)::text = 'participation'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'active'::text))
         ->  Index Scan using index_users_on_id_and_type on users u  (cost=0.42..8.45 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=0 loops=9751)
               Index Cond: (id = ds.user_id)
               Filter: ((properties -> 'provider'::text) = 'twitter'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Limit  (cost=29.83..29.84 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.953..2.954 rows=1 loops=2787)
           ->  Sort  (cost=29.83..29.84 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.951..2.951 rows=1 loops=2787)
                 Sort Key: ds2.id
                 Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on daily_statistics ds2  (cost=25.80..29.82 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.381..2.702 rows=105 loops=2787)
                       Recheck Cond: ((user_id = u.id) AND (campaign_id = 4742))
                       Filter: (((metric)::text = 'participation'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'active'::text))
                       ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=25.80..25.80 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2.365..2.365 rows=0 loops=2787)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_user_id  (cost=0.00..5.60 rows=156 width=0) (actual time=0.072..0.072 rows=292 loops=2787)
                                   Index Cond: (user_id = u.id)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_campaign_id_and_type  (cost=0.00..19.95 rows=453 width=0) (actual time=2.241..2.241 rows=9751 loops=2787)
                                   Index Cond: (campaign_id = 4742)
   SubPlan 2
     ->  Limit  (cost=29.83..29.84 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.879..2.880 rows=1 loops=2787)
           ->  Sort  (cost=29.83..29.84 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.876..2.876 rows=1 loops=2787)
                 Sort Key: ds2_1.id
                 Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on daily_statistics ds2_1  (cost=25.80..29.82 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.241..2.585 rows=105 loops=2787)
                       Recheck Cond: ((user_id = u.id) AND (campaign_id = 4742))
                       Filter: (((metric)::text = 'participation'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'active'::text))
                       ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=25.80..25.80 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2.222..2.222 rows=0 loops=2787)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_user_id  (cost=0.00..5.60 rows=156 width=0) (actual time=0.062..0.062 rows=292 loops=2787)
                                   Index Cond: (user_id = u.id)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_campaign_id_and_type  (cost=0.00..19.95 rows=453 width=0) (actual time=2.124..2.124 rows=9751 loops=2787)
                                   Index Cond: (campaign_id = 4742)
   SubPlan 3
     ->  Limit  (cost=29.83..29.84 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=3.030..3.030 rows=1 loops=2787)
           ->  Sort  (cost=29.83..29.84 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=3.018..3.018 rows=1 loops=2787)
                 Sort Key: ds2_2.id
                 Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on daily_statistics ds2_2  (cost=25.80..29.82 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.407..2.755 rows=105 loops=2787)
                       Recheck Cond: ((user_id = u.id) AND (campaign_id = 4742))
                       Filter: (((metric)::text = 'participation'::text) AND ((status)::text = 'active'::text))
                       ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=25.80..25.80 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2.390..2.390 rows=0 loops=2787)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_user_id  (cost=0.00..5.60 rows=156 width=0) (actual time=0.121..0.121 rows=292 loops=2787)
                                   Index Cond: (user_id = u.id)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_daily_statistics_on_campaign_id_and_type  (cost=0.00..19.95 rows=453 width=0) (actual time=2.233..2.233 rows=9751 loops=2787)
                                   Index Cond: (campaign_id = 4742)
 Total runtime: 25158.063 ms
(49 rows)


foobar_production=> \d daily_statistics;
                                       Table "public.daily_statistics"
    Column     |            Type             |                           Modifiers
---------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer                     | not null default nextval('daily_statistics_id_seq'::regclass)
 type          | character varying(255)      |
 metric        | character varying(255)      |
 campaign_id   | integer                     |
 user_id       | integer                     |
 country_id    | integer                     |
 attachment_id | integer                     |
 time_at       | timestamp without time zone |
 properties    | hstore                      |
 status        | character varying(255)      | default 'active'::character varying
Indexes:
    "daily_statistics_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_attachment_id" btree (attachment_id)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_campaign_id_and_type" btree (campaign_id, type)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_country_id" btree (country_id)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_id" btree (id)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_metric" btree (metric)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_properties" gin (properties)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_status" btree (status)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_time_at" btree (time_at)
    "index_daily_statistics_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
```

Thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, provide more input by following https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: @vyegorov see edit above

Comment: Please paste your code & results directly into the question, rather than posting to an outside service like pastebin. The external code can go away at any time, and there is no version control over it like with SO questions. Therefore, future readers may not be able to see the external code and thus this question will be useless or not make much sense. They certainly will not be able to find this question via keyword searching. StackOverflow is as much about future reference for others as it is about you getting your question answered today.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have 2 parts here:

1. first one is obtaining latest statistics for the users and
2. another one is accumulating all `attachement_id` for user.

Both for the specific type of statistics.
As you're interested in `users`, I would start with them at first place.

Search for the latest entries with this query:

```sql
SELECT u.id,
       ds.country_id,
       ds.time_at,
       ds.properties->'assumed_gender' AS assumed_gender
  FROM users u
  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT * FROM daily_statistics
       WHERE user_id=u.id
         AND campaign_id = 39
         AND metric = 'participation'
         AND status = 'active'
       ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
    ) ds ON true
 WHERE u.properties -> 'provider' IN ('twitter');
```

I use [`LATERAL` syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) here, which is nice for these kind of queries.

Aggregation will not benefit from it though, therefore another subquery is required.

I ended up with the following final query:

```sql
SELECT u.id,
       ds.country_id,
       ds.time_at,
       ds.properties->'assumed_gender' AS assumed_gender,
       g.attachment_ids
  FROM users u
  JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * FROM daily_statistics
     WHERE user_id=u.id
       AND campaign_id = 39
       AND metric = 'participation'
       AND status = 'active'
     ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
    ) ds ON true
  JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, json_agg(to_json(attachment_id)) AS attachment_ids
      FROM daily_statistics
     WHERE campaign_id = 39
       AND metric = 'participation'
       AND status = 'active'
     GROUP BY user_id
    ) g ON g.user_id=u.id
 WHERE u.properties -> 'provider' IN ('twitter');
```

I assume, that index:

```
CREATE INDEX i_ds_campaign4status
 ON daily_statistics(campaign_id, user_id, id)
 WHERE status='active';
```

will help. This depends on your data, though, if all your stats are `active`, than remove the `WHERE` clause.

---

**EDIT:** Based on provided plans, second query benefits from the join with an aggregate, as it reduces the iteration count for the `LATERAL` part.
I would stick with this approach.

Comment: @vyegov Yipes, the first query takes much longer. Almost 184 seconds. The final query much faster. Less than a second :D

Comment: @ChristianFazzini, perhaps this is due to caching effects. Can you provide `EXPLAIN (analyze, buffers)` output for both, please? You can paste your plans into http://explain.depesz.com/ and post links as comment here.

Comment: Sure, I've changed the id of the campaign to reflect the one that has thousands of records. The first one: http://explain.depesz.com/s/lztw The second one: http://explain.depesz.com/s/Obb

Comment: @ChristianFazzini, not so handy to look at the obfuscated plans... Are you sure your stats are up to date? What indexes you have right now?

Comment: Didn't change any indices